# How to speed up my R code?

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

I have some troubles with a code which take a huge amount of time to run.

```
for (k in 1:length(df_2L)) { 
  mat = matrix(99,nrow=dim(df_2L[[k]])[1],ncol= (dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]))
  for(j in 1:dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]) {
    for(i in 1:dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]) {
      if (df_2L[[k]][j] == df_2L[[k]][i]) {mat[i,j]<-1} 
      else {mat[i,j]<-0}
      }
    }
  assign(paste0("mat_2L_",k),mat)
  }

matall_2L_coassign <- lapply(ls(pattern="mat_2L_"),get)
matSum2L_coassign<-Reduce('+',matall_2L_coassign)

write.table(matSum2L_coassign,"matSum2L_coassign.txt",
            quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=F,dec=".",sep="\t")
```

Note that:

```
length(df_2L)[1]  
#[1] 38
```

and

```
dim(df_2L[[k]])[1] 
#[1] 503
```

---

**one day later...**

Some information on my data structure:

```
str(lapply(df_2L[1:2], head))
List of 2
 $ :Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ V1: int [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 $ :Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ V1: int [1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1
  ..- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `df_2L` is a list (with length 38) of 1D arrays (with dimension `503`).

---

In a loop nest, code optimization should start from inner layers to outer layers. You could replace

```
mat = matrix(99,nrow=dim(df_2L[[k]])[1],ncol= (dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]))
for(j in 1:dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]) {
  for(i in 1:dim(df_2L[[k]])[1]) {
    if (df_2L[[k]][j] == df_2L[[k]][i]) {mat[i,j]<-1} 
    else {mat[i,j]<-0}
    }
  }
```

by a vectorized beast:

```
mat <- outer(df_2L[[k]], df_2L[[k]], "==") + 0
```

By apply `==` with `outer` you get a FALSE/TRUE logical matrix, then the `+ 0` coerces it into a 0/1 binary matrix.

---

Now the transformed code has only a single loop.

```
for (k in 1:length(df_2L)) {
  mat <- outer(df_2L[[k]], df_2L[[k]], "==") + 0
  assign(paste0("mat_2L_",k),mat)
  }

matall_2L_coassign <- lapply(ls(pattern="mat_2L_"),get)
```

It is clear that you ultimately want to gather all temporary results into a list. Then, why not use `lapply` straightaway?

```
matall_2L_coassign <- lapply(df_2L, function (x) outer(x, x, "==") + 0L)
```

---

The final issue that is computation-related, is

```
matSum2L_coassign <- Reduce('+', matall_2L_coassign)
```

This is actually good enough.

---

Final code:

```
matall_2L_coassign <- lapply(df_2L, function (x) outer(x, x, "==") + 0L)
matSum2L_coassign <- Reduce('+', matall_2L_coassign)
write.table(matSum2L_coassign,"matSum2L_coassign.txt",
            quote=F,row.names=F,col.names=F,dec=".",sep="\t")
```

---

**one day later...**

Thanks for posting information on your data structure. So you actually have a list of data tables. In this case we have to first coerce it into a list of vectors (or 1D arrays).

```
## extract first variable of a data frame / table into a vector
df_2L <- lapply(df_2L, "[[", 1)
```

Then you can use my answer above.

Comment: Oh my god it is so fast compare to my first code!!! Thank you so much!!